# How can I present a Sheetpresentation controller behind the tabbar

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to show the sheetpresentation and also the tabbar how can I do that?

```
    let panelTopresent = DetailViewController()
    if let panel = panelTopresent.sheetPresentationController{
        panel.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
        panel.preferredCornerRadius = 20
        panel.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
    }

    panelTopresent.definesPresentationContext = true
    tabBarController?.present(panelTopresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can present TabBarController inside UISheetPresentationController if you want behaviour similar to Find My application. If you want sheet inside only one tab then it is not possible yet unless you create your own custom container and sheet presentation that will mimic Apple implementation